# SQL - INSERT new row by using sum of two existing rows from same table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I'm struggling with writing a working SQL script that takes two rows from same table and inserts the new row in the same table by copying the values from any of the original row except one column which uses the sum of the two rows.

Table looks something like this and the resulting insert i want to get

```
--------------------------------------------------           
| activity | place | begin_date | end_date | price |        
--------------------------------------------------         -------------------------------------------
| running  | gym   | 2020-6-1  | 2020-7-1  |  10   |   >   | sports | gym | 2020-6-1 | 2020-7-1 | 30 |
---------------------------------------------------        -------------------------------------------
| jumping  | gym   | 2020-6-1  | 2020-7-1  |  20   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Problem is i need to group by 3 columns (place, begin date and end date) as i have many different places, and begin and end dates. And i want to combine only running and jumping activities into sports all other activities should be unaffected.

Comment: I think you are just asking for `GROUP BY`.  Are you familiar with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that you are going to want throw a case statement into your select statement for 'activity' and then aggregate your price with the SUM() function. It would look like something like this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table
( activity
, place
, begin_date
, end_date
, price
)
SELECT CASE WHEN activity = 'running' OR activity = 'jumping' THEN 'sports' ELSE activity END
, place
, begin_date
, end_date
, SUM(price)
FROM dbo.Table t
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN activity = 'running' OR activity = 'jumping' THEN 'sports' ELSE activity END
, place
, begin_date
, end_date
```

Comment: Of course this is probably simpler then what you need. Make sure to add any filtering (WHERE Clause) that you need and any table and column aliasing that you would need.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO table (activity, place, begin_date, end_date, price)
SELECT 'sport', [place], [begin_date], [end_date], SUM([price])
FROM table
WHERE activity = 'jumping' OR activity = 'running'
GROUP BY place, begin_date, end_date
```